# Sliding Menu in Angular not behaving properly via $provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Problem**

I have a slider menu that I created as a navigation feature in a mobile app. The menu is generated just fine, it is compiled and shows up. I can flick the first couple links, and then push the back drop and it will close, however when I click the very last of the links, it doesn't close at all. It doesn't even respond. I have to restart the app, I have the inspector open and it doesn't show any errors. So I'm assuming the template is messed up, there's nothing wrong in the template. The source code for the provider seems to look okay, maybe there is an ordering issue?

Secondly, I am passing the `menuInstance` variable to all areas where it would be needed, and am trying to set a self-closing function, but that is not being recognized either. So all of this together potentially made for a really cool feature but alas, nothing is working correctly, except for opening.

So how do I get it to recognize it's instance so I can close the window on command from within it's own controller, and secondly why won't it recognize itself after the last link is pushed.

Here is a fiddle for the menu so that you can see behavior:

https://jsfiddle.net/Mr_Pikachu/4brubsst/49/

**Current Source Code (Strict Mode)**

```
/**
* Angular Slider Menu Widget
*/

// generate initial module and child modules
angular.module('sw.js.widget.slidermenu', ['ngAnimate', 'ngRoute']);
angular.module('sw.js.widget.slidermenu').directive('menuOverlayBackdrop', MenuOverlayBackdropDirective);
angular.module('sw.js.widget.slidermenu').directive('menuSlideCall', MenuSlideCallDirective);
angular.module('sw.js.widget.slidermenu').factory('$sliderMenuStack', SliderMenuStackFactory);
angular.module('sw.js.widget.slidermenu').provider('$sliderMenu', SliderMenuProvider);


// inject dependecies for each module as needed
MenuOverlayBackdropDirective.$inject = ['$sliderMenuStack'];
SliderMenuStackFactory.$inject = ['$document', '$compile', '$animate', '$rootScope'];

// create module functions
function MenuOverlayBackdropDirective($sliderMenuStack){
    return {
        compile : function(element, attrs){
            element.addClass('widget-show');
            return linkFn;
        }
    };
    function linkFn(scope, element, attr){
        scope.$on($sliderMenuStack.MENU_CLOSING, function(){
            var instance = $sliderMenuStack.get();
            instance.close(instance);
        });
    }
}


function MenuSlideCallDirective(){
    return {
        templateUrl : function(elem, attrs){
            return attrs.templateUrl;
        },
        compile : function(element, attrs){
            element.addClass('slide-left');
        }
    };
}

function SliderMenuStackFactory($document,  $compile, $animate, $rootScope){
   $menuStack = {
        'MENU_CLOSING' : 'closing',
        'MENU_CLOSED' : 'closed',
        'instance' : null,
        'menu' : null,
        'open': function(menuInstance, menu) {
            //console.log(menuInstance, menu);
            //menuOpts.scope.main = menuOpts.menu.main;
            var appendToEl = menu.appendTo;
            var backdropEl = angular.element("<div class='widget-backdrop' menu-overlay-backdrop></div>");
            var backdropScope = $rootScope.$new();
            backdropEl.bind('click', function(){
                backdropScope.$broadcast($menuStack.MENU_CLOSING);
            });
            var menuEl = angular.element("<div class='slider-menu-container' menu-slide-call template-url="+menu.template+"></div>");
            
            menuInstance.backdropEl = backdropEl;
            menuInstance.menuEl = menuEl;
            menuInstance.scope = menu.scope;
            menu.scope.close = menuInstance.close;
            $menuStack.set(menuInstance);
            
            $compile(menuEl)(menu.scope);
            $compile(backdropEl)(backdropScope); 
            $animate.enter(backdropEl, appendToEl).then(function(){
                $animate.enter(menuEl, appendToEl);
            });
           
        },
        'close' : function(menuInstance){
            menuInstance.scope.$apply(function(){
                $animate.leave(menuInstance.menuEl).then(function(){
                    menuInstance.backdropEl.remove();
                    menuInstance = null;
                    $menuStack.set(menuInstance);
                });
            });
        },
        'set' : function(instance){
            $menuStack.instance = instance;
        },
        'get' : function(){
            return $menuStack.instance;
        },
        'remove' : function(){
            $menuStack.instance = null;
        }
    };

    return $menuStack;
}

function SliderMenuProvider(){
   $menuProvider = {};
    $menuProvider.options = {
        background : true
    };
    $menuProvider.$get = ['$sliderMenuStack', '$q', '$rootScope', '$controller', '$document', function($sliderMenuStack, $q, $rootScope, $controller, $document){
        return {
            open : function(menuOptions){
                var menu = {};
                // preparing a new instance of the menu to be injected
                var menuInstance = {
                    close : function(){
                        $sliderMenuStack.close(menuInstance);
                    }
                };
                menuOptions = angular.extend({}, $menuProvider.options, menuOptions);
                var providedScope = menuOptions.scope || $rootScope;
                menuScope = providedScope.$new();
               // menuScope.$close = menuInstance.close();
                menu.scope = menuScope;
                menu.appendTo = $document.find('body').eq(0);
                menu.template = menuOptions.templateUrl;
                
                // generate the controller and then create an instance of the controller to be used
                var ctrlInstantiate = $controller(menuOptions.controller, {$scope : menuScope}).constructor;
                $sliderMenuStack.open(menuInstance, menu);
            }
        };
    }];
    return $menuProvider;
}
```

Here is the page template that I am trying to load:

```
<main class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>
        <section class='col-xs-12'>
            <ul class='list-group headed-list-group'>
                <ng-repeat ng-repeat='(k, track) in tracks'>
                    <li class='list-group-item list-group-heading'>{{k}}</li>
                    <li class='list-group-item title clearfix' ng-repeat="t in track">
                        <div class='col-xs-2'></div>
                        <div class='col-xs-8'>
                            <table class='track-table'>
                                <tr><td class='track-title'>{{t.name}}</td></tr>
                                <tr><td class='track-cat'>{{t.subtitle}}</td></tr>
                                <tr><td class='track-stats'></td></tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-xs-2'>
                            <p class='text-center form-control-static text-right'>
                                <!--<i class='fa fa-ellipsis-v' downloads-drawer></i>-->
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ng-repeat>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

So after a few hours of reading and some experimenting on code I have the working solution after all!

You have to inject the menuInstance into the controller via the `locals` option and then update the code accordingly. I have the examples below along with the working fiddle.

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Mr_Pikachu/4brubsst/51/

**SOLUTIONS**

*$sliderMenu*

**from**

```
var ctrlInstantiate = $controller(menuOptions.controller, {$scope : menuScope).constructor;
```

**to**

```
var ctrlInstantiate = $controller(menuOptions.controller, {$scope : menuScope, $menuInstance : menuInstance}).constructor;
```

*$sliderMenuStack*

**from**

```
'close' : function(menuInstance){
     menuInstance.scope.$apply(function(){
         $animate.leave(menuInstance.menuEl).then(function(){
             menuInstance.backdropEl.remove();
             menuInstance = null;
             $menuStack.set(menuInstance);
         });
     });
 }
```

**to**

```
'close' : function(menuInstance){
    $animate.leave(menuInstance.menuEl).then(function(){
         menuInstance.backdropEl.remove();
         menuInstance = null;
         $menuStack.set(menuInstance);
    });
 }
```

*menuOverlayBackdrop*

Update the entire return statement to the following:

```
return {
    compile : function(element, attrs){
        element.addClass('widget-show');
        return linkFn;
    }
};
function linkFn(scope, element, attr){
    scope.$on($sliderMenuStack.MENU_CLOSING, function(){
        var instance = $sliderMenuStack.get();
        instance.close(instance);
        instance.scope.$apply(function(){
            $animate.leave(instance.menuEl).then(function(){
                instance.backdropEl.remove();
                //menuInstance = null;
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Then lastly make sure when you call the provider you include the `$menuInstance` injection variable in the controller function to ensure that everything is working correctly.